# i am trying to print words from a sentence in c++ but its giving me Segmentation Fault(core dump)

Tags: c++, string, char

I am trying to print the words from a sentence but it's giving the error:

> Segmentation Fault (core dump)

Is it due to the use of `gets()` function, or is it something else?

```
void words(char* sentence){
    int len =strlen(sentence);
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
        char word[100];
        int j=0;
        while(sentence[i]!='\0' || sentence[i]!=' '){
            word[j++] = sentence[i++];
        }
    word[j] ='\0';
    cout<<word<<endl;
    }
}
int main(){
    char str[100];
    gets(str);    
    words(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Btw: Do not use char arrays in C++, you have http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/ class

Comment: `sentence[i]!='\0' || sentence[i]!=' '` is simply `true`. It would only be false if `sentence[i]` was both `'\0'` and `' '` which is impossible.

Comment: **Don't** use `gets` in C or C++.  It was deprecated and has since been removed from C and C++.

Comment: thank you  @François Andrieux  it workd now:

Comment: Change `||` to `&&` for start.

Comment: You have buffer overflow if User types more than 100 characters.  Good reason to use `std::string` and not `gets`.  You can't limit the character count with `gets`.

Comment: The `word` array lives **only** inside the `for` loop.  You can't access it after the `loop`.  You may want to move the `word` array to before the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main code itself is not proper.
char str[100];
    gets(str);

How you will make sure that always input to str will be 100.If input exceed 100 it will cause crash.

Comment: *"it will cause crash"* - no, it will invoke *undefined behavior*

Comment: yes it is a undefine behavior :)  if memory you are accessing belongs to your process.But if i memory you are trying to access belong to different process than program will crash.